What's the resource group equivalent of subscriptionResourceId and managementGroupResourceId in Bicep?
In Bicep, I can use subscriptionResourceId() or managementGroupResourceId() to refer to a resource at the subscription or management group level, respectively.
In the following code, I'm using subscriptionResourceId() to create a (RBAC) role assignment at the subscription level for a system-assigned managed identity and an Azure Key Vault:
resource keyVaultRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(
    subscription().id,
    subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6')
  )
  scope: keyVault
  properties: {
    principalId: appServiceApp.identity.principalId
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
      'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions',
      '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6'
    )
  }
}

How would I get the resource's resource group ID? The resourceId() function depends on the scope of the deployment, and so is ambiguous

you mean you need the keyVaultRoleAssignment resource group id ?

Independent of your question, can I ask what is the actual outcome you're looking for?


How would I get the resource's resource group ID?

Here is the updated code to fetch the resourcegroup ID from a resource (app service) and assign a role to the app service identity at the resource group level.
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' existing = {
  name: 'samplevksb'
}
// Extract the resource group name from the Key Vault resource ID
var appserviceResourceGroupName = split(appService.id, '/')[4]
 
// Construct the resource group ID
var appserviceResourceGroupId = subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', appserviceResourceGroupName)
 
// Output the resource group ID of the Key Vault
output appserviceResourceGroupIdOutput string = appserviceResourceGroupId
 
resource keyVaultRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(
    appserviceResourceGroupId,
    subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6')
  )
  scope: resourceGroup()
  properties: {
    principalId: '83-4afa99ea1946'
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
      'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions',
      '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6'
    )
  }
}

Output:

After running the code, the role assignment has been assigned at the resource group level for the system-assigned managed identity.


Wouldn't it make more sense for Azure to add a resourceGroupId() function, like the management group and subscription ones? Why do you specify roleDefinitionId using subscriptionResourceId()? Shouldn't you specify it as resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6')?

When specifying roleDefinitionId, doesn't it matter whether you reference the role at the management group, subscription, or resource group level?

If you use the resourceGroup().id function, you will get the current resource group ID, not the resource group ID of an existing resource. For the roleDefinitionId, you can also use resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6'),which will produce the same output. A simplified way is to store the role in a variable and use it in the role assignment step, like here. Refer MSDoc for more details.

When you specify the roleDefinitionId like resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6'), it will assign the role to the current resource group automatically without the scope option. If you want to assign the role to another resource group, you can use the method shown here without specifying subscriptionResourceId() and resourceId().

I hope this helps resolve your issue.

I don't agree. The definition of resourceIdsays: The format of the returned identifier varies based on whether the deployment happens at the scope of a resource group, subscription, management group, or tenant., so your statement of When you specify the roleDefinitionId like resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6'), it will assign the role to the current resource group automatically without the scope option. seems not to be true

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource#resourceid

In my case, it assigns to the current resource group without specifying a scope if I use the resourceId, and I have tested this in my environment.

If you're operating within the scope of your resource, then you can just use resourceGroup().id to get the resource's resource group ID right?

Thank you. What do you mean by within the scope of your resource?

The default scope when you deploy a resource is at the resource group level, which is what your code snippet implies (else you would have used modules to change the scope).
For this snippet of code, when you deploy using either Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell, you'd most likely be using either az deployment group create  or New-AzResourceGroupDeployment. Both of these require a resource group parameter—this sets the scope in which you'll deploy the resource.
So when you run resourceGroup().id, it's getting the resource group of "this" deployment.

Thank you again. Could you name a module for changing the scope?

There's no module to change the scope of a deployment. Instead, you can use the resourceGroup() function to change the scope when you deploy a resource. Have a look at the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-scope#resourcegroup, specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-scope#resource-group-example on how to set the scope of a deployment.
